# after install magento 2 admin and front end object not found

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento and after installation when accessing **Admin and Front End**, it throws error

> forbidden

I tried reinstalling many times but throws error in admin and front end:

> object not found

I already tried every solution I got here or from google but didn't solve and 
I also already tried to change

```
.htaccess
FrontNameResolver
httpd.conf
httpd-xampp.conf
etc
```

I'm use `xampp` and install it in windows

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After installation please run these couple of command in magento root:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Please do not change anything in .htaccess file.

Comment: that's for windows? how i run it?